# How to send parameters from a notification-click to an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, notifications

I can find a way to send parameters to my activity from my notification.

I have a service that creates a notification. When the user clicks on the notification I want to open my main activity with some special parameters. E.g an item id, so my activity can load and present a special item detail view. More specific, I'm downloading a file, and when the file is downloaded I want the notification to have an intent that when clicked it opens my activity in a special mode. I have tried to use `putExtra` on my intent, but cant seem to extract it, so I think I'm doing it wrong.

Code from my service that creates the Notification:

```
        // construct the Notification object.
     final Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());


    final RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, tickerText);
    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progress,100,0, false);
    notif.contentView = contentView;        

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("item_id", "1001"); // <-- HERE I PUT THE EXTRA VALUE
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    nm.notify(id, notif);
```

Code from my Activity that tries to fetch the extra parameter from the notification:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        Log.i( "dd","Extra:" + extras.getString("item_id") );
    }
```

The extras is always null and I never gets anything into my log.

Btw... the `onCreate` is only run when my activity starts, if my activity is already started I  also want to collect the extras and present my activity according to the item_id I receive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Take a look at this guide ([creating a notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)) and to samples ApiDemos "StatusBarNotifications" and "NotificationDisplay".

For managing if the activity is already running you have two ways:

1. Add  **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** flag to the Intent when launching the activity, and then in the activity class implement  **onNewIntent(Intent intent)** event handler, that way you can access the new intent that was called for the activity (which is not the same as just calling getIntent(), this will always return the first Intent that launched your activity.
2. Same as number one, but instead of adding a flag to the Intent you must add **"singleTop"** in your activity AndroidManifest.xml.

If you use intent extras, remeber to call `PendingIntent.getActivity()` with the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, otherwise the same extras will be reused for every notification.

Comment: and to answer the user's question about extras being null: You have to call `PendingIntent.getActivity()` with the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, otherwise the same extras will be reused for every notification.

Comment: u saved my day but why is transferring simple data like this so complicated in android

Comment: If you should have different notifications make sure to use different request IDs when calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()` in addition to setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` on the `Intent` and `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` on the `PendingIntent`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370324/notification-passes-old-intent-extras

Comment: @Matthias It seems `onNewIntent()` is no longer used. and.. `PendingIntent.getActivity()` with the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` saved my day! Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. I spent hours debugging trying to figure out why the intent wasn't passing the extras, and `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 105):

I had the similar problem my application displays message notifications.
When there are multiple notifications and clicking each notification it displays that notification detail in a view message activity. I solved the problem of same extra parameters is being received in view message intent.

Here is the code which fixed this.
Code for creating the notification Intent.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), viewmessage.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", notificationMessage);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),notificationIndex,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

Code for view Message Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("NotificationMessage"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.viewmain);
            // extract the extra-data in the Notification
            String msg = extras.getString("NotificationMessage");
            txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
            txtView.setText(msg);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 33):

Maybe a bit late, but:
instead of this:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Log.i( "dbg","onNewIntent");

    if(extras != null){
        Log.i( "dbg", "Extra6 bool: "+ extras.containsKey("net.dbg.android.fjol"));
        Log.i( "dbg", "Extra6 val : "+ extras.getString("net.dbg.android.fjol"));

    }
    mTabsController.setActiveTab(TabsController.TAB_DOWNLOADS);
}
```

Use this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}
```

Comment: Maybe late for the OP, but it's never late for the others in the Internet :)

Answer (score 22):

Encounter same issue here.
I resolve it by using different request code, use same id as notification, while creating PendingIntent. but still don't know why this should be done.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, **id**, notificationIntent, 0);
notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;
nm.notify(**id**, notif);
```

Comment: you made my day!!!

Comment: It works. Thinking about how it worked!

Answer (score 16):

After reading some email-lists and other forums i found that the trick seems to add som unique data to the intent.

like this:

```
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);
   notificationIntent.putExtra("sport_id", "sport"+id);
   notificationIntent.putExtra("game_url", "gameURL"+id);

   notificationIntent.setData((Uri.parse("foobar://"+SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())));
```

I dont understand why this needs to be done, It got something to do with the intent cant be identified only by its extras...

Comment: Anroid reuses intents, the intent action and request code make it unique, but not the extra data. So you need to set a unique request id or use different intent actions.

Answer (score 10):

I tried everything but nothing worked.

eventually came up with following solution.

1- in manifest add for the activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"

2- while making pending intent do the following, use bundle instead of directly using intent.putString() or intent.putInt()

```
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseActivity.class);

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(Constants.EXAM_ID,String.valueOf(lectureDownloadStatus.getExamId()));
                    bundle.putInt(Constants.COURSE_ID,(int)lectureDownloadStatus.getCourseId());
                    bundle.putString(Constants.IMAGE_URL,lectureDownloadStatus.getImageUrl());

                    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                            new Random().nextInt(), notificationIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: It works for me. Must using different requestCode value and  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag.

Answer (score 5):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Include launchMode="singleTop"

```
<activity android:name=".MessagesDetailsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        />
```

**SMSReceiver.java**

Set the flags for the Intent and PendingIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessagesDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("smsMsg", smsObject.getMsg());
    intent.putExtra("smsAddress", smsObject.getAddress());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notification_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**MessageDetailsActivity.java**

onResume() - gets called everytime, load the extras.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String extraAddress = intent.getStringExtra("smsAddress");
    String extraBody = intent.getStringExtra("smsMsg");
```

Hope it helps, it was based on other answers here on stackoverflow, but this is the most updated that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy,this is my solution using objects!

**My POJO**

```
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private int age;

    //get & set

}
```

**Method Notification**

```
  Person person = new Person();
  person.setName("david hackro");
  person.setAge(10);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Person.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("person",person);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorTipografiaAdeudos))
                .setPriority(2)
                .setLargeIcon(bm)
                .setTicker(fotomulta.getTitle())
                .setContentText(fotomulta.getMessage())
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(fotomulta.getTicketText())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
```

**New Activity**

```
 private Person person;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_push);
    person = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("person");
}
```

**Good Luck!!**

Answer (score 4):

In your notification implementation, use a code like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY", "value");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
nBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
...
```

To Get Intent extra values in the ExampleActivity, use the following code:

```
...
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent!=null) {
    String extraKey = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY");
}
...
```

**VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:** the **Intent::putExtra()** method is an Overloaded one. To get the extra key, you need to use **Intent::get[Type]Extra()** method.

*Note: **NOTIFICATION_ID** and **NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID** are an constants declared in ExampleActivity*

Answer (score 3):

After doing some search i got solution from android developer guide

```
PendingIntent contentIntent ;
Intent intent = new Intent(this,TestActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra","Test");
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

stackBuilder.addParentStack(ArticleDetailedActivity.class);

contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

To Get Intent extra value in Test Activity class you need to write following code :

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra") ;
```

Comment: What is `stackBuilder` for?

Answer (score 2):

Please use as PendingIntent while showing notification than it will be resolved.

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Add PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as last field.

Comment: Tested on Android 10. Working.

Answer (score 1):

G'day,
I too can say that I tried everything mentioned in these posts and a few more from elsewhere.
The #1 problem for me was that the new Intent always had a null bundle.
My issue was in focusing too much on the details of "have I included .this or .that".
My solution was in taking a step back from the detail and looking at the overall structure of the notification. When I did that I managed to place the key parts of the code in the correct sequence.
So, if you're having similar issues check for:

```
1. Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);

2a. Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
```

//I like specifying the data type much better. eg bundle.putInt

```
2b. notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
3. PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, WIZARD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
4. NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
5.          NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(content)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                            .setAutoCancel(false)//false is standard. true == automatically removes the notification when the user taps it.
                            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            notificationManager.notify(WIZARD_NOTIFICATION_ID, nBuilder.build());
```

With this *sequence* I get a valid bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
android:taskAffinity="myApp.widget.notify.activity"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file for the Activity to launch, you have to use the following in your intent:

```
Intent notificationClick = new Intent(context, NotifyActivity.class);
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putSerializable(NotifyActivity.Bundle_myItem, myItem);
    notificationClick.putExtras(bdl);
    notificationClick.setData(Uri.parse(notificationClick.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME) + myItem.getId()));
    notificationClick.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  // schließt tasks der app und startet einen seperaten neuen

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotifyActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationClick);

    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);
```

Important is to set unique data e.g. using an unique id like:

```
notificationClick.setData(Uri.parse(notificationClick.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME) + myItem.getId()));
```