# Sending data from service to activity

Tags: java, android

I am having issue when sending data from Service to Activity through Notification , I click a Notification an Activity get invoked but when i try to add some parameters through bundle i am not able to get the parameters in that called intent , I have gone through the link 
[How to send parameters from a notification-click to an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity)

But still no luck.

Has the same issue occurred with somebody else ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you send data from service to activity?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to modify the Manifest file as well.

Here is the example that works:

These variables and methods are members of Service class:

```
public static final String MOVEMENT_UPDATE = "com.client.gaitlink.AccelerationService.action.MOVEMENT_UPDATE";
    public static final String ACCELERATION_X = "com.client.gaitlink.AccelerationService.ACCELERATION_X";
    public static final String ACCELERATION_Y = "com.client.gaitlink.AccelerationService.ACCELERATION_Y";
    public static final String ACCELERATION_Z = "com.client.gaitlink.AccelerationService.ACCELERATION_Z";

private void announceAccelerationChanges()//this method sends broadcast messages
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MOVEMENT_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(ACCELERATION_X, accelerationX);
        intent.putExtra(ACCELERATION_Y, accelerationY);
        intent.putExtra(ACCELERATION_Z, accelerationZ);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

And this are the methods from Main activity:

You have to register receiver in the onResume method:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {   

        IntentFilter movementFilter;
        movementFilter = new IntentFilter(AccelerationService.MOVEMENT_UPDATE);
        accelerationReceiver = new AccelerationServiceReceiver();
        registerReceiver(accelerationReceiver, movementFilter);


        startAccelerationService();

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void startAccelerationService()
    {
        startService(new Intent(this, AccelerationService.class));
    }

    public class AccelerationServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
      @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)//this method receives broadcast messages. Be sure to modify AndroidManifest.xml file in order to enable message receiving
        {
            accelerationX = intent.getDoubleExtra(AccelerationService.ACCELERATION_X, 0);
            accelerationY = intent.getDoubleExtra(AccelerationService.ACCELERATION_Y, 0);
            accelerationZ = intent.getDoubleExtra(AccelerationService.ACCELERATION_Z, 0);

            announceSession();

            updateGUI();
        }
    }
```

This is the part of AndroidManifest.xml file that has to be set in order to receive broadcast messages:

```
<activity android:name=".GaitLink"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="com.client.gaitlink.CommunicationService.action.ACTIVITY_STATUS_UPDATE" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working as expected ..
i have written Log statements but is is not displaying in  onRecieve method .what wrong i may be doing i am doing the same as said!

Comment: Does the service broadcast the message?
Has the BroadcastReceiver been started and running in the activity?
Have you added intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i have added BroadcastReceiver  in AndroidManifest.xml file , yes the service does the broadcast how can i confirm that the BroadcastReceiver  has been started.

Comment: Niko, your example is working very well. It was helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code doesn't 100% work, but using broadcasts and BroadcastReceivers was exactly what I wanted to use

Comment: For completeness you may want to add a notice about unregistering the broadcast in the onPause method.

Comment: +1 Wow, finally a good and "correct" solution for communication between `Service` and `Activity`. Thank you!