# android: how to pass view reference to a service

Tags: android, service, view, reference

I have a sound recorder app. I have a service where the recording happening. I want to display a waveform during recording, I have a custom View for it, but it needs the byte array, which the recorder writes. My activity and my service communicates with messages and messagehandlers. I don't want to send the whole data to the view via messages every time I update the waveform. Is it possible somehow to send the View reference to the service?

Comment: For me this reads like a "how to update the ui from a service"-problem. Does this question helps you by any means? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942083/updating-ui-from-a-service-using-a-handler

Answer (score 1):

For a Service to trigger something in the UI, you don't send a View to it. However, Android does have several ways to accomplish Service-Activity communication. The documentation has an overview [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). Pick your favorite method and find a tutorial; they're not very tricky, with the possible exception of using AIDL.