# How to create a service that check message has come from server in Android?

Tags: android, service

I want to create a background service which continuously check that is there any message that has come from server.

I am trying using AsyncTask but I am not getting how can I know when any message will come or has arrived.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way from [here.](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard : I will take care of it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are polling at a set inerval to your web server to figure out the state. Simply read the response from your web server and take action.

Read this post
[Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

Alternately try using the Cloud to device messaging.

If you want to go really large scale use XMPP.