# How to add my app's icon into the status bar when my app is running?

Tags: android

I tried to use the `Notification.Builder` and the `Notification` classes.

I tried using this code :

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
notification.notify();
```

but it seems useless.

I only want my app's icon to be added next to the battery icon,wifi icon and 3g icons.. Any way to do that? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show an icon in the status bar when application is running, including in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973208/how-to-show-an-icon-in-the-status-bar-when-application-is-running-including-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call the method build() after you have finished describing your notification. Check out the [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) for an example.

Basically, you have to change your code to the following:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context )
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);      

Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mID , intent, 0);
builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification notif = builder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(mID, notif);
```

**Note**: this code will only allow to show your icon in the notification bar. If you want it to persist there, you will have to use [FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949726/persistent-service-icon-in-notification-bar)

Comment: The previous code was to simply show the proper ordering to show the icon. I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: That doesnt add the icon to the right where the battery and signal icons are.

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer In that case, this question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350016/how-to-create-a-notification-status-bar-icon-on-the-right-side

Answer (score 0):

You can add your app icon for status bar notification. Try this one

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).build();
```