# How to add icon in the notification slider in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, slider

I want to create icon like this in notification slider to start the service Just like Bluetooth, Wifi or Mobile Data

[image]

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949726/persistent-service-icon-in-notification-bar

Comment: Those are called Quick Settings Tiles. I think the only real documentation for them is on [the `TileService` page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService).