# Sending data from service to activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I want to schedulers background service to run a scan method.
so the service will update the number of scanned file.
how can i handle the case that i closed the app schedulers run the service, the update ui method will crash and stop running the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my case

I changed the structure to let the service to send a broadcast and receive it in the activity.

Comment: How often u send data from service to activity? How this influence performance if u send it let's say 10x per second? 10q

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging). Its a very good example of `Service`. It illustrates both way communication.

Comment: i change the structure to let the service to send a broadcast and receive it in the activity

Comment: you really don't need to send a broadcast from service to transfer data. There is `ServiceConnection` and `Messenger`class to help you do that specific job. But thats ok if it works! :)

Comment: ServiceConnection still alive when i closed the activity ??