# send intent from service to activity

Tags: android, service, android-intent, intentservice

I'm trying to return the result from an `IntentSerivce` to the `mainactivity` using an intent, but I can't get it to work.
The `IntentService` receives the intent from the activity without a problem, does it's thing and gets a `JSONstring`. Now the only problem left is to send this String back to the activity.

Here is the method in the mainactivity:

```
public String RTConn(String query){
    System.out.println("Querying Rotten Tomatoes.");
    Intent rtIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RTConnection.class);
    rtIntent.putExtra("query", query);
    bindService(rtIntent, RTConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(rtIntent);
    String json = getIntent().getStringExtra("json");
    return json;
```

And here is the IntentService:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    System.out.println("intent Received");
    String jsonString = rottenTomatoesSearch(intent.getStringExtra("query"));
    Intent RTRetur = new Intent(RTConnection.this, MainActivity.class);
    RTRetur.putExtra("json", jsonString);
    startActivity(RTRetur);
}
```

Obviously the startActivity isn't working, but what else is there to use? (I would rather not use a broadcast receiver).
Regards Peter L.

Update

this it how the MainActivity looks atm:

```
public static final String RECEIVE_JSON = "student.kau.RECEIVE_JSON";
private BroadcastReceiver RTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("broadcast Received: "+intent.getAction());
        if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_JSON)){
            System.out.println("JSON Received.");
            String serviceJsonString = intent.getStringExtra("json");
        }
    }
};
```

This code is the onCreate:

```
LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVE_JSON);
    bManager.registerReceiver(RTReceiver, intentFilter);
```

This is the method:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    System.out.println("intent Received");
    String query = intent.getStringExtra("query");
    String jsonString = rottenTomatoesSearch(query);
    System.out.println("Fetching done");
    Intent RTRetur = new Intent(MainActivity.RECEIVE_JSON);
    System.out.println("action: "+RTRetur.getAction());
    RTRetur.putExtra("json", jsonString);
    sendBroadcast(RTRetur);

}
```

The last trace in logcat is the `System.out.println("action: "+RTRetur.getAction()");`

```
-action: 

    student.kau.RECEIVE_JSON
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For this, you can use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your `Activity`.

[Here is a great example I use](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) to communicate continuously between `Service` <> `Activity` using `BroadcastReceivers`.

[Here is another great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging) of communication between Service <> Activity. It uses `Messenger` and `IncomingHandler`.

### BroadcastReceiver

I will make a quick example for your case.

This is your BroadcastReceiver for your Activity. It is going to receive your String:

```
//Your activity will respond to this action String
public static final String RECEIVE_JSON = "com.your.package.RECEIVE_JSON";

private BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_JSON)) {
            String serviceJsonString = intent.getStringExtra("json");
            //Do something with the string
        }
    }
};
LocalBroadcastManager bManager;
```

In your `onCreate()` of the activity

```
bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVE_JSON);
bManager.registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In your `onDestroy()` of the activity, make sure you unregister the broadcastReceiver.

```
bManager.unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
```

And finally, in your `Service onStart()`, do this:

```
System.out.println("intent Received");
String jsonString = rottenTomatoesSearch(intent.getStringExtra("query"));
Intent RTReturn = new Intent(YourActivity.RECEIVE_JSON);
RTReturn.putExtra("json", jsonString);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(RTReturn);
```

and your Activity will receive the intent with that json in it as an extra

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but is it really "best practice" to use a broadcast receiver when you just want to send a string from a service to a prespecified activity?

Comment: Of course, it's not the only way to do it, and I don't know if it's a best practice or not, but it's quite easy to set up. I will give you some other examples of communicating between Service <> Acitivty

Comment: The "private broadcastReceiver breceiver = new BroadcastManager()" line does not work, shouln't it be "private BroadcastReceiver breceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()"?

Comment: It's good to know I'm not totally lost then. To bad i still can't get my receiver to receive any broadcasts.. :(

Comment: I updated my code. There might've been an issue with the intentFilter constructor. Try it now

Comment: I've tried your changes not and still nothing everything seems to work right up to when the receiver should catch the broadcast. So I'm guessing there is still something missing. But I can't for the world figure out what it might be..

Comment: Updated the question now with the new codesnippets so you can see the changes I've made.

Comment: Edited my answer. Seeing as you use LocalBroadcastManager, you have to use that to send the broadcasts too. Forgot about that.

Comment: Well look at that it works!
Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: It didn't work for me because I had a Service in a different process. In this case, LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast() wouldn't work, only Context.sendBroadcast()