# Messages between Service/Activity

Tags: android

Sorry for asking such a basic question, I know a good bit of Java but am just trying my hand at Android now. I was just wondering was there a simple way to send messages between Activity and Services in Android. I have looked at this guy's implementation:

[Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

But it still seems a bit verbose, and specific to his design, application needs. I have the service running and bound to the Activity, but when it comes to actually using the Message.obtain() method, I'm not really sure what I should be passing in as parameters, I don't even understand how the process of sending the message is actually working. 
Is there any other simple methods offered by Android to send messaged between the two?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The API guides provide information about how to [bind services to the application and interact with them through messages](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger). And as stated at the end of the linked chapter, the SDK includes simple examples of how to implement that.

Comment: cheers man, ya i need to start a bit more simply i think and work up

Comment: Usually SO is the best place to find answers to really strange problems, but for the basic stuff is always recommended to start from the Android guides to avoid finding really weird or messed up code ;)

Comment: There are other options for communicating between services and activities, e.g., intents (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), and often this can be a simpler way to communicate, though generally not ideal when there needs to be a lot of back and forth communication.