# Use arraylist and adapter from other class

Tags: java, android, static, arraylist

I want to use a Adapter and a ArrayList declared in Inicio.java from a Service for example:

In Inicio.java

```
public static AdaptadorImagenes adaptador;
public static ArrayList<String> pathImagenes;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_incio);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.hide();

            }
            contexto = getApplicationContext();
            datos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            pathImagenes = new ArrayList<String>();

            recojeDatosDeSesion(savedInstanceState);
            adaptador = new AdaptadorImagenes(contexto);
```

And service.java

```
                Inicio.pathImagenes.add(pathImagen);
```

The activity start the service, but when i try to do Inicio.pathimagenes this return me nullpointer exception.

Comment: Don't try to use objects that belong to an Activity in a Service. So something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the list at declaration (not in `onCreate`):

```
public static ArrayList<String> pathImagenes = new ArrayList<String();
```

Comment: public static AdaptadorImagenes adaptador = new AdaptadorImagenes();
No enclosing instance of type Inicio is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Inicio (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Inicio).

Yes but for the adapter? Before works for me but i dont know how i had change..