# Do I need a Service in my android application?

Tags: android, android-service

In my Application I have several Activities and a Java class with a thread. This thread continuously receives and sends messages to the web server. The Application is working fine in testing but I am worried that it may not when being used in actual phones. I am afraid that my background thread which continuously interacts with the Server might be killed by Android, while the app is in background.

Do I really need to make my threaded client class a service ? I want to start it when user signs in and stop it when the user logs off from the system.

If I need to do it please suggest some easy tutorial for it.

Comment: It is always better to use services to perform continusly running tasks. However you should also look at **STICKY** concepts.

Comment: please go through the below tutorial.. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See these links..

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

[Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/simple-example-of-service-in-android.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as i think you better use TimerTask along with Timer along with any normal class or service will suffice your objective.

Comment: How a timer can suffice my task ?

Comment: Timer launch your job at regular intervals