# developer.android.com Service tutorial not clear

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to understand the tutorial on the android developer web site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

I understand most of it expect where its uses this bit code in the "Remote Messenger Service Sample" section of the tutorial ...

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
        IBinder service) {
    ...

    Toast.makeText(Binding.this, R.string.remote_service_connected,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

... where is `Binding.this` defined? Is that a typo? There are several other places in the tutorial where `Binding.this` is used but there is no explanation about what `Binding` is or how it gets initialized.

`Binding.this` gets used here like so ...

```
void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because there is no reason to be able to let other
    // applications replace our component.
    bindService(new Intent(Binding.this, 
        MessengerService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
    mCallbackText.setText("Binding.");
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the outer containing class. In this case, you can see by its usage it derives from `Context`. By the naming, you can deduce that it's the class that's binding to the `Service`, most likely an `Activity`.

Comment: Yes ... I needed to change `Binding` to `MainActivity` (the name of my Activity class). Thanks!

Comment: BTW I found that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging is a FAR better tutorial than the one on developer.android.com.