# Persistent Service on Android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am trying to write a service that comes with a `MediaPlayer`. I have different Activities accessing it, so I thought it would be best to peruse a Service.

It works fine so far, I have also added a call to `startForeground`, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). The notification shows up.

But when I now press the home or back button on the device, the service is stopped and `onDestroy` is called, and the notification icon disappears. When I return, the service seems to reBind just fine.

I stop the music playback on `onDestroy`, so of course it stops. But I would like to keep the notification and service alive even when the user is on another app.

**EDIT**: I hope this is the relevant part:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {
    private static class PlayerMessageHandler extends Handler {
        private final MediaPlayerService owner;

        public PlayerMessageHandler(MediaPlayerService owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Handle
        }
    }

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 13138;

    private final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new PlayerMessageHandler(
            this));
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Notification notification;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        startNotification();
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.v(TAG, "Media player service created.");

        player = new AudiobookPlayer(this);
        new Thread(seekerUpdate).start();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(TAG, "Media player service destroyed.");

        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.pause();
        }
        sendMessageToUI(MSG_PLAYER_HAS_PAUSED);

        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void sendMessageToUI(int msg) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Sending " + msg);

        sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, msg));
    }

    private void sendMessage(final Message message) {
        // Send
    }

    private void startNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
        builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        notification = builder.build();

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**: Methods from the activity, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to the service
    bindService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class),
            playerServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (bound) {
        unbindService(playerServiceConnection);
        bound = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: @Bex: The question is how I get the service to stay alive even when the user is on another app.

Comment: I think, you need a Wakelock to let the service persist

Comment: @flx Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @flx : the service stops when the **Home** button is pressed, so I don't see how's that relevant to WakeLocks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your service [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY). In fact, this is what the [tutorial uses](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService):

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
...

 @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      ...

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }
...
}
```

**EDIT:** from the discussion that transpired since, turns out that my suspicion was correct, and Hugo provided a spot-on diagnosis. I guess you now need to add `builder.setOngoing(true);` in `startNotification()`.

Comment: @LambdaDusk: That's... unusual. Can you edit the question with your code?

Comment: I hope I have all the relevant parts.

Comment: @LambdaDusk : I may be wrong, as it's been a while since I wrote a Service, but I don't see anything wrong with the parts you posted. However, I have a suspicion - can you also include your Activity's `onPause`?

Comment: I have no `onPause`, only `onStart` and `onStop`, added above

Answer (score 4):

Extracted from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
Bound

> A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, get results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. **Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.**

You are binding your Activities on `onStart` and unbinding on `onStop`. When you press Home or Back, your last foreground Activity may call `onStop`, unbinding the last Activity from the Service and killing it.

An alternative solution would be call `startService` so the `onStartCommand` will be called, then calling the `bindService` to bind the Activities.

Comment: I did that, now the Service seems to hang around, but the notification disappears. And Re-opening the app kills and re-starts it.