# How to implement streaming media player as foreground service?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, foreground-service

Am trying to make an streaming MediaPlayer. There is categories for songs and Each category contains number of songs. I have implemented MediaPlayer  in Service. For the communication between Activity and Service i have used messages,intents, and runnable. But my issue is that App not responding smoothly. Swipes and Clicks are very slow. And Checking on RAM usage , app's ram usage going high on playing songs.

Please help me out from this issue,

Thanks and regards,

Comment: use "local bound service" pattern instead of "messages,intents, and runnable", and no, i dont have any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging), it has an example to bind service with your activity. Personally I prefer to bind service with activity to be able to control the player, instead of sending intent or message because it takes a slighting more time like 0.5 - 1 second.
Also I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417679/android-media-player-using-service) in the past, you can check it, it might help you.