# Comunicate two differents projects with same service

Tags: java, android, service

I have to implement a service that runs in background and then an different app that take service's results and represent its.

I did an activity than launch a service and even if this app is destroyed service continues to run.

activity:

```
package com.example.pruebaservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button telo, telo2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        telo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        telo.setOnClickListener(this);
        telo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        telo2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            startService(new Intent(this, PruebaService.class));
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            stopService(new Intent(this, PruebaService.class));
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

service:

```
package com.example.pruebaservice;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PruebaService extends Service {

    private Sistole_main telo;
    private static final String SISTOLE_FOLDER = "SISTOLE_Audio";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio creado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("SERVICEBOOT", "Servicio creado");

        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, SISTOLE_FOLDER);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File file2 = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "trig.pcm");
        if (!file2.exists()) {
            AssetManager manager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
            try {
                InputStream movefile = manager.open("trig.pcm");
                String ruta = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "trig.pcm";
                OutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(ruta);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int tam;
                while ((tam = movefile.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    salida.write(buffer, 0, tam);

                }
                salida.flush();
                salida.close();
                movefile.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.gradiant,
                "Servicio SISTOLE", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "SISTOLE",
                "Calculando coordenadas", pi);
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        startForeground(1337, note);

        telo = new Sistole_main();
        telo.control(1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("SERVICEBOOT", "Servicio destruido");
        telo.control(0);
    }
}
```

this code runs OK.

But now the question.. How can I do to create a second project that access to this service and take coordinates values?

Help?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to use a `ContentProvider` to provide access between different apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support multithreading in your service then you need [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). If not then a [Mesenger](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) will work OK. There is example code in the samples that come with the SDK, you should find them in all platform revisions under api e.g

C:\YourRoot\tools\android-sdk-windows4.4\samples\android-7\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app..

Look for the files starting Remote...java and those which are *.aidl

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging) for a wonderful example

Comment: @upenpat - not that wonderful really, as both the activity and the service are in the same application. If you had looked at the manifest more carefully, you would have noticed that.

Comment: what i meant was that it was simple example which demonstrates Messenger usage.