# how to get data from one service to another in android

Tags: java, android, service

I am new to android development, i am working on a project in which i have to create two service namely ***service1*** and ***service2***.

My ***service1*** will run always while it starts a new service called ***service2*** which will run for some time perform some work and stop.

***service2*** has to read/access and change the value of some data members of the 
***service1*** and get destroy automatically every time after completing the execution.

Till now i came to know i want to perform some inter service communication.

I dont know how to do this... Kindly help me to solve this problem.

***Service1 Code Snippet***

```
class Service1 extends Service{
        private int counter = 0;
//some code
@Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(); 
Intent i= new Intent(this,StratCounterService.class);
        startService(i);
}
//some code
    public int getCounter() {
            return counter;
        }
```

This is the code which i am using in the class Service1.java

***Service2 Code Snippet***

```
public class Service2 extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(20000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    if(getCounter()>=someInteger) doSomthing();
                    else {
                        mInitialized=false;
                        //And stop this service here!
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


}
```

Thanx in advance..

Comment: You can save it into Bundled extras in Intent that fire service. Try to look on http://stackoverflow.com/a/21565858/1370062

Comment: I didnt get how to do this can you give examples to do this?

Comment: That examples are included in answer that I gave you. There is another one http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-intent

Answer (score 2):

you can use shared preference to store data and  can get it from your another service class

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)