# Real Time Communication between Devices and Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm Android Developer since a year ago, but I've never done any app which communicates between devices (just GET and POST calls).

I'm thinking about making a card game in Android Native (not Cocos2D-x or a game engine).

The way to communicate between devices is GCM, but I didn't fully understand how I can handle the game logic.

I know that the class `GCMIntentService` can Override:

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onRegistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onUnregistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {


}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {

    Log.e(TAG, "onError: errorId=" + errorId);
}
```

My question is: do I have to develop all the game logic on `onMessage()` ? could you provide me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: onMessage is just a method of your broadcast for GCM which gets called whenever there is a message from/between devices, the rest of the logic not need to be in there, but you can call them from onMessage if you require

Comment: I mean, the logic which interacts with the game... for example

I receive a {card:"4"}... do I have to send it to my current activity/fragment ?

Comment: it's obvious where you need it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the Activity (probably the game in your case):

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {

    Intent intent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    intent.putExtra(xxx,xxx); //try to put the require information from data intent
    context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

In a started activity case, use `PendingIntent` instead, with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag

Comment: But along the activity I would need to communicate between them as well

Comment: @Rafa Firenze: this topic may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging

Comment: Ok, then that means that I have to control all the game's logic depending of the message, no?. For example, if I'm notificating the free rooms on my game, if you are inside a room, if you are playing... all that logic is handled right there by sending data from Service to Intent... is that right?

Comment: @Rafa Firenze: true, then your activities can base on the intent and the message to do certain logic