# How to communicate with a service from Activity launched by this service itself

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a service 'MyService' running in background which launches an activity 'MyActivity' on certain event (code below).

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

'MyActivity' perfroms some action and has to communicate back to 'MyService' but I do not know how it can be done since there is no reference to service.

Please note 'MyService' extends 'HostApduService'. I have just checked in docs that **HostApduService** has declared 'onBind' as final

```
@Override
public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

So I can not use the service binding mechanism, right?

Any pointer please?

Thanks
iuq

Comment: use Binder in service ,you can look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: perhaps its time to learn Service binding... :)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging?rq=1

Comment: I have updated my question. Can I still use service binding?