# How to send data to the fragment from an activity that does not own it?

Tags: android

I cannot seem to find this anywhere. Here is the issue:

I have a Fragment A that comes from Activity A.  This fragment launch Activity B.

I want to send From Activity B to Fragment A.  How is that done?

Comment: send what? what have you tried, so far? BroadcastReciver? Service? custom Application class? why don't you return data from Activity B to A and then let the Activity A send it to Fragment A ...

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, is there a more direct solution. The problem is that the activity A could be destroyed after launching activity B

Comment: I tried using persistence where setting a Boolean in the bundle. But it seems like a hack

Comment: yeap it can ... then save somewhere in Activity B and reaload Fragment A in onStart of Activity B ... still i don't have such problems because most of time i'm using own ContentProviders to store data ... so if i save something somewhere in other app's component all others components(using the same data) will know about it because of ContentObserver stuff ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use 'startActivityForResult()'.  This will start the activity, and then when it's done, it will allow you to return some data to a callback function in the fragment that you override.  Here's an example:

```
private void ActivityBStarter(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
    startActivtyForResult(i);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //use data.get...  to get data from the activity.
    //This is only called when the activity completes.
}
```

Then in the activity, do this when you want to finish the activity and pass the result back:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent); //RESULT_OK can really be any int you want.
finish();
```

Alternatively, you could use Messengers and message passing to pass data between your Activity and fragment as ActivityB is running, but that's usually not very useful unless you're using a Service.

Here's a link:
[Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

Good luck!