# Android: How do I call startResolutionForResult from a Service?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I'm trying to add GPS tracking functionality to my app by writing a GPS tracking Service. I've been following the Android Developer materials on how to do this via Google Play Services, but I'm stuck on the `onConnectionFailed` method. I'm trying to call `startResolutionForResult` to let Google Play Services handle the error. However this method requires that an activity be passed in as the first parameter, and since I'm calling it from a Service I'm not really sure what I should do.

I assume that I'm going about this all wrong and there's a completely different way to handle this from a service.

Answer (score 2):

The authentication process for Google Play Services needs an activity since it may need to display UI to the user.  Since services don't have UI, you need to send a message to an activity to set up the connection, then the service can continue.  There is a good answer demonstrating one way to do this here: [Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

Comment: Such a strange solution. As it was announced on googleIO2015 user can disable some permissions. And how service should show UI dialog for user?! It's weird.

Comment: The new functionality in M will most likely change this behavior.  Stay tuned!

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson How to do that properly? Should I just pass the `ConnectionResult` in a message to the activity and then in the activity call `startResolutionForResult`? Will that connect the API client used by the service, or should the service call `connect()` afterwards. Also, can I be sure this does not leak the Activity to the API connection used by the Service?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Status.getResolution()** and start Activity with it. For example:

In Service

```
PendingIntent pI = status.getResolution();
mGoogleApiClient.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(mGoogleApiClient.getContext(), SomeActivity.class)
.putExtra("resolution", pI).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

In Activity onCreate:

```
PendingIntent pI = (PendingIntent) (getIntent().getParcelableExtra("resolution"));
startIntentSenderForResult(pI.getIntentSender(),1,null,0,0,0);
```

also add **onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)** to receive result of resolution

Comment: the resolution also can be obtained from the exception using (ResolvableApiException) e;