# How can one ellicit a Toast from a Service to a Fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a button that sends an Intent to a Service to execute some code.  How would one ellicit a Toast in the Fragment once the Service has finished executing the code?

Comment: What are you trying to do presently? (Show some code)

Answer (score 0):

why you can't perform Toast from Service?

if you really need to send data from Service to Fragment you should use service binding ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)) then from Activity to Fragment