# how to send data to Service in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

i have a service running in my app. It listens for messages from a server then sends the message to  the mainactivity. How can I send data back to the service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

Comment: the same way you are sending them from the service

Comment: You should include at least a part of the code you are using to give us some context.,