# Share data between activity and service android

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am doing an android application , i want to get data from activity to a service
and then this service wil make a notification and send datat to another activity and the user can see the result in activity  ? please hep me

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

Comment: I want to get the data first from activity A to service S and send data to activity D?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in Activity from where you want to send data:(msg is data you want to send)

```
    Intent myintent = new Intent("package name of class where you want to send");
    myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
    myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//You might need this
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(myintent);
```

In onCreate() of your receiver activity :
Add this :(anywhere after setting content view)

```
         getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("package name of current class i.e receiver"));
```

Add this in class :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Data received is : " +  intent.getStringExtra("message"));
   //Make a Notification here
    }
};
```

Also(In receiver Activity) :

```
  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("package name of current class i.e receiver"));
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: How did you can send messages to service ?

Comment: GCM!!
What about Handler?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)