# Dont stop the service when back was pressed

Tags: android

I have a `Map activity` and `MainActivity`. The MainActivity communicate with Service class that contains LocationManager. When the button was clicked  in the MainActivity  then the Map Activity is opened.

I want to stop the Locationmanager in the service class just when the App was closed or the Trackingservice checkbox button in the menu in the MainActivity was set to false (This is another button than the one  which starts the Map activity) but I dont want to stop it when I  press the `back` button and I want to  go from the Map to the MainActivity since  with the current state the `onBackPressed()`  then the `onDestroy()` are being invoked in the Map Activity, after that the `onDestroy()` method in the `Trackingservice` class is being called  which leads on to stop the Tracking service.

How can I reach that?

As I said I want to stop the service when the app is being closed in the Background (not matter in the MainActivity or Map activity) or the Tracking service check box button was set to false which works fine at the moment but I dont to stop the service when the `back` button was pressed which does not work at the moment because is being stoped.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_available);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    stopService(i);
}
}
```

**Service class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    LocationManager lm;

    private void detectLocation() {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15 * 1000, 0,
                this);
        enableGPS(lm);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);

    }
}
```

**Map Activity**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        markerMap.clear();      
        stopAlarm();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        GetLLRD.shouldContinue = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        markerMap.clear();      
        stopAlarm();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to bind service, [like here in doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). there is a lot of questions with answers and even working examples ([here probably the best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)) about that on stack. then you may decide when you want to unbind and destroy service and when to leave it in background. other Activities may also bind to this Service and communicate as well

Comment: to keep service alive you don't have to bind it to activity!

Comment: thats true, but he was asking about keeping alive `Service` only when `Activity` is using it

Answer (score 1):

you can put your app in the background instead off finishing it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 moveTaskToBack(true);
// super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Really helped. Thanks for sharing :)