# Send event to another application

Tags: android, android-activity

I know that all android applications run in their sandboxes and that the only way to communicate with then is using intents and content providers. Anyway I want to ask if there is any method to send to the another activity EVENTS? I want to send to another application's activity touch event from my service

Comment: Yes.  In general, you communicate between activities with with "intents".  If you want to communicate from a *service*, you can use a "broadcast": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464853/sending-data-from-service-to-activity  or, better, "binding": http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: Yes, I know... But is it possible to send events for any application?...

Comment: @nandeesh please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send key and touch events from some other application, you will need root access to do this.