# Can't put extras for an intent in notification

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-intent, extra

I'm creating a notification from a Service that has an intent with an extra integer. For some reason, this isn't as easy as it seems. This is what I'm doing:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, "Title", 0);
Intent relaunchIntent = new Intent(this, SomeClass.class);
relaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
relaunchIntent.putExtra("load", getId());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title", "Tap here to open", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, relaunchIntent, 0);
notificationManager.notify(1234, notification);
```

And then from SomeClass, it reads like this...

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    load(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("load", -1));
```

What's weird is that I get inconsistent results when I read the value from the `getInt()` method. Sometimes I get values of things I set in a previous notifications. For example, I get a value of 3 when I had set that extra to be 4. I know this is very confusing and strange, which is why I'm wondering if anyone has experienced anything like this and what you may have done to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: May want to take a look at using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` from the comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity/1201239#1201239).

Comment: Thanks, the answer to that question did the trick. You should consider putting it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using [`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) when you call `PendingIntent.getActivity`. From the documentation:

> This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras
>   change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous
>   PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if
>   they are not explicitly given to it.

I ran into this issue myself, and found the answer from a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity/1201239#1201239).