# How to set click listener for notification?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I am using the following code to launch a notification when a Service is started Via AlarmManager:

```
nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
CharSequence from = "App";
CharSequence message = "Getting Latest Info...";
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
    "Getting Latest Info...", System.currentTimeMillis());
notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, contentIntent);
nm.notify(1, notif);
```

How do I set an intent for this item so that when the user clicks on it, it would launch a certain activity?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You basically need to put the Activity class as part of your intent into your PendingIntent. Currently your Intent is empty. To redirect to new activity, it should be:

```
// This line of yours should contain the activity that you want to launch. 
// You are currently just passing empty new Intent()
PendingIntent contentIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Also i know this outside the question, is there anyway i could set a a Extra to be passed with it?

Comment: @yoshi24: i guess you can add a bundle to the intent.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself yet, but this post seems to answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity

Comment: @yoshi24: oops i guess you posted while i was typing. :)

Answer (score 31):

As for yoshi24's comment, you may be able to set extras like this.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setData(data);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

You need to be aware of this as well before going for pending intents

[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity)

**UPDATE**
some thing like this will work for you

int your mainfest

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" ... />
```

in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    processIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     
    processIntent(intent);
};

private void processIntent(Intent intent){
    //get your extras
}
```

Comment: What is the Link you posted refering to, that i am trying to do?

Comment: you have to change the intent flag as **android:launchMode="singleTask"** in the manifest and override **onNewIntent(Intent intent)** inside the activity. this will enable you to receive the parameters.

Comment: Could you put that in your answer too?

Comment: @yoshi24: could you select my response also as answer. i guess we can select more than one. but i dont know if it is possible. **and of-course if it works for you**.

Comment: I wish i could, but that would be wrong to take the answer away from the first answer. I want to but i dont think it would be fair. Im sure you will get plenty of vote ups when people come across this

Comment: @yoshi24: i didn't mean to takeaway, i guessed to mark two responses as answer, its a tick. looks like check-boxes. ;).

Comment: @yoshi24: i tested it in one of my questions, and oops it **toggles**.

Comment: +1 for [onNewIntent(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))!

Answer (score 10):

I did it,

- I add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to new intent

  ```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
          "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
  // Hide the notification after its selected
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoficationDemoActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("buzz", "buzz");
  intent.putExtras(bundle);
  PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is the title",
          "This is the text", activity);
  notification.number += 1;
  notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
  ```
- Oncreate i do as follow:

  ```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
      Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  ```