# Launch a Notification and when tap on it, run other function

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

Solved. This question was resolved by Diego D.

This code launch a Notification by a function: **Notification(final String mytext)**.
We get that Notification with ticker, title, text, autocancel,... when tap on it, run other function: **My_Function(mytext)**;

To work, it doesn't need modify AndroidManifest because use Broadcasts.

```
public void Notification(final String mytext) { 
final Intent notifIntent = new Intent("action_call_method");
PendingIntent pendingmyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if (intent.getAction().equals("action_call_method")) {
                My_Function(mytext);
            } 
        }
    };

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("action_call_method");
context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
         .setTicker(ticker)
         .setContentTitle(title)
         .setContentText(text)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_lock_silent_mode_off) 
         .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setContentIntent(pendingmyIntent)
         .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set click listener for notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184963/how-to-set-click-listener-for-notification)

Comment: This is not duplicate because in this post needs run Other function in same class file and doesn´t use AndroidManifest

Comment: @canel You're welcome ! By the way I just renamed myself because that was a very old stack account haha. *-previously Theodore M.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a custom action for the `Intent` in your `PendingIntent` and register a receiver to it, then you'll be able to do what you want:

```
Intent notifIntent = new Intent("action_call_method");
PendingIntent pendingmyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then register a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("action_call_method")) {
                // Call your method here
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("action_call_method");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Don't forget to unregister your receiver.