# Passing widget id to activity

Tags: android, android-widget

In my widget provider, I have the following code:

```
for (int widget_id : appWidgetIds) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Widget Id: " + widget_id);
  RemoteViews remoteViews;

  Widget widget;

  while (true) {
    try {
      widget = Widget.load(context, Widget.class, widget_id);
      break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Exception!", ex);
    }
  }

  // Widget is assigned to user
  if (widget != null) {
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_with_user);
    remoteViews.setCharSequence(R.id.user_text, "setText", widget.user.name);
    remoteViews.setUri(R.id.avatar, "setImageURI", Uri.parse(widget.user.avatar));
  }
  else {
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, ConfigureWidget.class);
    configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
    configIntent.putExtra("widget_id", widget_id);

    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.configure_text, configPendingIntent);
  }

  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widget_id, remoteViews);
}
```

In the else section, I'm launching a configuration activity and trying to pass the widget id to it. However, the bundle is always null:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
  int widget_id = extras.getInt("widget_id");
}
```

How can I get the widget id to the launched activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that android does caching with PendingIntents. The solution was to add the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag which causes it to update the cached PendingIntent.

```
PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code instead:

```
if (extras != null) {
  int widget_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("widget_id", defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> public Bundle getExtras ()
>   *Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.*

*[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29)*

Same goes for `Intent.putExtra(Bundle)`. These are extended attributes. 
Try using [`getIntent().getIntExtra(String key, int defaultValue)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) instead.

Comment: `public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)`
Retrieve extended data from the intent.

Same goes for `getIntExtra`

Comment: Mh you are right, the emphasize on extended is not correct here. Still they are seperated values if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to properly register the intent filter in your manifest? For some reason, extras don't get passed properly without an explicit action, and it might not be working right if you haven't setup the intent filter.