# Why extra data (integer) is not sent in android notification intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

The following code to display a notification and send int data, but in the other activity `getExtras()` returns `null`. Why?

```
int notificationID = 1;
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownlodResult.class);
i.putExtra("notificationID", 1);


PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);


CharSequence tickerText = "There are updates !";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
Notification notification = new Notification(icon,tickerText,when);
CharSequence contentTitle = "There are updates";
CharSequence contentText = "Please click here to view it";
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);



notification.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500}; // Needs vibrate permissions
nm.notify(notificationID, notification);
```

Answer (score 15):

Probably the PendingIntent exists already and was not created, but reused. Try to create it with the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330144/530804 and the other answer on that question.