# Android Phonegap GCM Multiple Notification

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using Phonegap with GCM plugin to show GCM notification.
I am able to display notification correctly but I am not able to show multiple notification. I tried [Notification passes old Intent Extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370324/notification-passes-old-intent-extras?rq=1) but No results yet.
Please help.

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);

       // saveCallIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, JainDharma.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, iUniqueId, notificationIntent, 0);
        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, UNIQUE_INT_PER_CALL, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. Are you getting any error messages. What have you tried. Have you tried debugging? What did you learn from doing that? Posting a new question on StackOverflow should be your last resort after you have tried and researched the problem all you can. Provide all information you gather during that process here, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the last notification overrides the previous one, and you wish to change it, you need to change the following :

`notificationManager.notify(0, notification);`

Use a different id (instead of `0`) for each notification and you'll see all of them.

However, you might want to reconsider whether it's such a good idea to show multiple notifications for the same app. I would find that annoying as a user of your app.

Comment: We are not pushing many notifications same day.. its for news 1-2 per day.

Anyway thanks alot