# Android Notification setContentView

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
Page says that, I have to use Intent

I can't use Intent because my code have only one Activity. I want to use notification to get back to app e.g. from **DEVICE'S HOME SCREEN**.

I have to use Intents when I want to execute something by clicking the notification. Is there a way to use `setContentView` after clicking the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing what you have attempted so far, I am going to take a stab at this one.

I don't quite see why regardless of how many Activities you have in your app, you cannot *declare / use* an `Intent`. If you need to trigger your only Activity again, after a Notification has been clicked, and need to call the `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_xml);` in the Activities `onCreate()` again, why not declare an Intent for your Notification like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

This way, clicking on your Notification should do what you want it to do.

*Again, this may or may not work for you considering that you haven't posted any code at all.*

**EDIT:** Based on the comments by the OP, what I **think** the solution maybe:

Refer to this link on how to send data with an Intent for a Notification: [How to send parameters from a notification-click to an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1198558/450534)

Basically, since a `Notification` has been triggered, I am assuming that the user has already logged in. Now to skip the login part when they come back to the app after clicking a `Notification`, send some extras along with the `Intent`. Then, when the `Activity` starts, check for the value and using an `if...else` statement, decide which layout should be shown.

Again, and I cannot stress this enough, you should always show what you have done so far. That really helps finding a solution. Your **actual requirement** has no bearing on what you need done at all.

Comment: When I clicked on Notification is just started new instance of my app. Application is based on LoginActivity, so I can't open login form everytime I open application from notification.

Comment: @Disa: What task do you want to run when the notification is clicked? A little more clarity in your question would really help.

Comment: Application is based on LoginActivity. When I start app, login form shoul appear. After successfully loging in main content should appear. When someone want to go back to home for some minutes, clicking the notification should show main content without reloging.

Comment: @Disa: So you have 2 activities right? Let assume, the first is LoginActivity and second is MainActivity? That okay?

Comment: I have only one Activity, but 3 layouts(login, main, addcontact). I call them by setContenetView when I need to display them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Intent to get back to the app, e.g. like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, intent, 0);
final Notification notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.logo, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: When I clicked on Notification is just started new instance of my app.