# How can i change the start page of Phonegap app in ios?

Tags: ios, cordova

Hello Anyone please tell me how can change the loading class in xcode like index.html to login.html in ios. I am new in ios so please help me.

Answer (score 9):

the proper way of doing this, and without code changes is changing this line on the config.xml from

```
<content src="index.html"/>
```

to

```
<content src="login.html"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I did is, xxxViewController: CDVViewController<...>

then you can write on  'init'  or 'viewDidLoad'

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.wwwFolderName = @"dist/view";
        self.startPage = @"test.html";
    }
    return self;
}
```

or

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    self.wwwFolderName = @"dist/view";
    self.startPage = @"test.html";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

so,that is all.

Comment: Awesome!!! I have been looking for this solution since the days...Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The following code will load an HTML file named index.html in your project folder:

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Comment: Thanks.. for give quick answer but I don't know where i put this code.. please explain this...

Comment: Please read out this post it will help you a lot:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview

Comment: @dgk: The question was about phonegap, not native development in objective-c

Comment: @NareshSaini: 10 seconds of research did provide the correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730695/how-to-set-the-initial-page-url-in-android-phonegap-based-application