# How can i pass extra string from Notification to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to pass value of my push notification to my activity. But it always returns null.

Here is how I am trying to pass extra string:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Register.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", new_key.toString());
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

// Play default notification sound
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Here is my activity where I am trying to get this extra string.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("NotificationMessage");
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello"+msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This toast always show me **" Hello null "**. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `PendingIntent` to your notification via `.setContentIntent()`. It will trigger intent when notification is clicked.

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        ...
        .setContentIntent(intent)
        ...
        .build();
```

Comment: Try with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: Hopefully this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity may help you.