# Activity handling in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I have an activity `A` that is either started from another activity `B` or via `PendingIntent` from a `Notification`, which is created in a service. The notification is shown regardless of the activity being started from another activity or not. `A` has a button which makes the activity close itself.

I now want to implement the following behavior:

1. If the activity `A` is run from `B` and the user touches the button, the app should return to `B`.
2. If the activity `A` is run from `B` and the user touches the notification, the running activity `A` should be shown. If the user touches the button, the app should return to `B`.
3. If the activity `A` is **not** run from `B` and the user touches the notification, A should be started. If the user touches the button, the App should be completely closed (except for `Services` / `BackgroundReceivers` running in the background).

What flags do I need to set / how do I start the `Activity`? Currently, activity `B` starts the service which creates `A` and the notification. The reason for this is that `A` might also need to be created from a `BroadcastReceiver`, which starts the service. Is this the right way?

Comment: Try Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK when launching Activity A.
Also do not set parent activity for Actiivty A, this will set the default behaviour of back button.

Comment: I tried that, but when call `finish()` in `A` in scenario 3, the activity just gets minimized. I want to actually close the application.

Comment: Then try calling finish() on button click.

Comment: That is exactly what I do, yet the activity does not close. It only minimizes and can be opened again. Is there any good way to inspect the `BackStack` to debug this?

Comment: Looks like you want to remove your app to remove from android app history stack?
This can be done by ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo but it is not a good way as you are changing default behaviour here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as I understood, you want to know how to handle the button in A activity. if it came from a notification, you finish the app when the button is clicked. If it was already there, you just finish the activity.

I would say to [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840955/2652124). So, you can use the `onNewIntent` method to handle it. The flag to update will handle when A is already running.