# Android app does not open on tapping notifications appearing on top of device screen

Tags: android, android-intent

When the user drags down all notifications and then tap on my app notification, then the app opens.

However, if a fresh notification appears on top on device screen and the user taps it, it does not open.

What could be the issue?

```
        Intent intent = Activity1.createIntent(app.getApplicationContext());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
Activity2.createIntent(app.getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList<>(participants));
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
  PendingIntent.getActivity(app.getApplicationContext(), 1000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(app.getResources(), R.mipmap.appiconmain);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(app.getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_item_arrival, Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setLargeIcon(bm)
                .setContentTitle(displayNotificationData.getTitle())
                .setContentText(displayNotificationData.getSubTitle())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) app.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Can you provide some details on your push notification implementation? Are you using gcm or fcm?  Have you overridden `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived`? Are you sending standard "notification messages" or custom "data messages?

Comment: @AbtinGramian I do not override FirebaseMessagingService.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at overriding `Activity`'s `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` event handler, on this method you should be able to perform whatever tasks you need

Additionally, according to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) you can still get the original intent through via `getIntent()`, therefore still inside `onNewIntent()` you should consider using [`setIntent (Intent newIntent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent(android.content.Intent)) so you can use this new intent anywhere in the activity

> Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201239/2819928) quote from a precise and concise answer:

> For managing if the activity is already running you have two ways:
>
> - Add **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** flag to the Intent when launching the
>     activity, and then in the activity class implement **onNewIntent(Intent
>     intent)** event handler, that way you can access the new intent that was
>     called for the activity (which is not the same as just calling
>     getIntent(), this will always return the first Intent that launched
>     your activity.
> - Same as number one, but instead of adding a flag to the
>     Intent you must add "singleTop" in your activity AndroidManifest.xml.
>
> If you use intent extras, remeber to call PendingIntent.getActivity()
>   with the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, otherwise the same
>   extras will be reused for every notification.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use this :-

PendingIntent pendingIntent =
  PendingIntent.getActivity(app.getApplicationContext(), 1000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

and overrride onNewIntent method in your MainActivity.